# After Windows 10 new build 1511, my control Panel shows same installation date for everything

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

Today I updated Windows 10 to build 1511.

But after the installation, I noticed that control panel shows for almost every installed program same installation date, today's.

How is possible? Some programs that I installed a week ago or so, shows the installation day of today. But some of them show the correct installation date.

Why is this happening?

[image]

EDIT:

Actually control panel shows the wrong date. I compared it with the `C:Program Files/` and there the date is correct. What is going on?

Comment: IIRC, this is because of the update and expected behavior. This is the date you upgraded to build 1511.

Comment: Yes this date is the date when I upgraded to build 1511. 
But: **1)** Why just some programs show the wrong date **2)** Why in the C:Program Files/ the date is correct ?  So I have a program and in _control panel_  is written one date and in _drive C_ is written another date

Comment: Look here (seems that I am not the only one): https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3vsuui/why_does_the_date_of_installation_for_some_apps/

Comment: The install date in Control Panel comes from the Registry not Program Files. The Registry gets rebuilt during the 1511 upgrade. It looks like some dates don't get carried over. Since the 1511 update I've noticed that the dates can change when something else gets updated. I've had two other programs change today at the same time OneNote updated.

Comment: @DavidMarshall A ok tnx, didn't know. 
But look what I fould out. I was searching on internet for this programs that in control panel shows todays date (or other date but still not the same as in the C:Program Files/), and I found out that exactly on the same date (the one of the control panel) was the last release or update of this program (was looking at the websites of this programs). I dont have this release/update installed, but **is it possible that the winows new build looks at these dates and then this dates gets somehow in the control panel?** (I checked I think every program)

Comment: No, it doesn’t. Take a look at the registry, `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. That’s the place all this is stored.

Comment: @DanielB I looked and half of the dates does not match! This dates in registry are dates of the **first** installation or should be the dates of the **update** installation? becasue e.g. in registry there is written Intel Driver installed 1.10. but in the Program Files and in the control panel is written todays date...

Answer (score 0):

As previously said: 
This is a bug (AKA feature) of Windows 10.

Automatic Maintenance runs whenever it wants and changes registry keys for no good reason - including those that contain the installation date of programs.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug or a feature (Security & Maintenance -> Automatic Maintenance) of Windows 10

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.